# File Move throws IOException due to different mount volume in Linux

Tags: java, file-io

Hi my java program has to move the files to a folder which is in different mounted folder.
I want to treat it as a normal folder path and move the file using

```
boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(dir, file.getName()));
```

it gives the status as false always and file not moved.

When I try with the `filechannel.transferFrom(fcSource, 0, fcSource.size());` it is throwing IO Exception.

```
SEVERE 20110720 15.41.29 AccessLogProcessor:moveToArchive-File
    [/opt/apache2/logs/access_log.20110620.0015.tmp] move to
    [/opt/ahache2/logs/old] not success.. Try Special move with filechannel
SEVERE 20110720 15.41.29 AccessLogProcessor:moveToArchive-SpecialFileMove for file
     [/opt/apache2/logs/access_log.20110620.0015.tmp] failure
    ERROR:java.io.IOException: **No such file or directory
```

The destination folder in linux looks like normal and my id has no permission issue. The folder `/opt/ahache2/logs/old` is a mounted one.

Comment: Any move between mount points is actually a copy and delete.

Comment: According to your logs, '/opt/apache2/logs/access_log.20110620.0015.tmp' does not to exist.  Is it the file your are trying to move ?  Also, can you try to create a file in '/opt/ahache2/logs/old' ?

Answer (score 1):

About the `'renameTo'` returning false, and according to the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29):

> Whether or not this method can move a file from one filesystem to another is platform-dependent. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

So maybe you cannot use `'renameTo'` to do what you want to do.